# Will building older versions of the linux kernel on newer versions of Ubuntu work?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

Let's say that I need to port an older version of the Linux kernel (3.2 for example) to a custom board. I'll be cross-compiling from a Ubuntu environment.

Will I need to be running a certain version of Ubuntu to successfully build a certain version of the kernel, or will I be fine with any version of Ubuntu?

Comment: The result of cross compiling is generally not dependent on the OS that you do the compiling on.

Comment: you can cross compile required kernel on any version provided you have all required pre-requisites (toolchain, etc) to build the same.